# Avoiding the "default" property indirection with babel

Tags: javascript, module, babeljs, transpiler

I am using babel to transpile ES2015 code to ES5 & RequireJS.

But when I use the following syntax:

```
const o = { foo: 'foo' };
export default o;
```

The transpiled result is an object with a `default` property on it.

ie. it is currently transpiled to something like:

```
define(function() {
  return {
     default: { 
       foo: 'foo' 
     }
  };
});
```

What I want is the object literal itself (containing the foo property) to be returned directly.

ie. I want something like:

```
define(function() {
  return {
     foo: 'foo' 
  };
});
```

Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't include default it will work as expected.

```
export const o = { foo: 'foo' };
```